# How to disable paging for JpaRepository in spring-data-rest

Tags: paging, spring-data-rest

I'm using [spring-data-rest](/questions/tagged/spring-data-rest) with `JpaRepository` to create the Rest-Endpoints. By default, paging is enabled for all `JpaRepository`, what is a good thing. But I have a legacy application that we port to our new stack that does not support paging. I would like to disable paging depending on an URL-Parameter to still be able to use paging in new application code.

I tried various approaches to expose the resources with and without paging:

- Use `CrudRepository`: Results in only having an unpaged endpoint and the method `flush` is missing.
- Override the `List<T> findAll()` method in my repository interface and annotated it with `RestResource`. I would have expected that the method will be exposed as search method, but it is not.
- Annotate `Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable)` with `@RestResource(exported=false)` and annotate `List<T> findAll()` as in the bullet before. I have hopped that this replaces the default method. But this is not valid solution anyway, because only a non paged endpoint is exposed.
- Pass `size=-1` to get an unlimited result -> Default paging size is used

I've seen that the spring-controller `RepositoryEntityController` uses a `RepositoryInvoker` to call the methods on the repository.  The `Pageable` is resolved using the `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` which always returns a pageable (specified in query, annotated or default pageable). 
The only solution that I see for the moment is to implement a custom `PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` that returns null, if a custom url parameter is passed.

Do you know any other solutions or is anything similar planned for the future?

Answer (score 11):

I use PagingAndSortingRepository and this config to set my pageableResolver:

```
@Configuration
public class RestApiConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver customResolver(
        HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableResolver) {
        pageableResolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
        pageableResolver.setFallbackPageable(new PageRequest(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        pageableResolver.setMaxPageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        return pageableResolver;
    }
}
```

See: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-929

This way if page and size are included in the request you get the page requested, but if they are not in the request you get all records. In both cases if a sort is specified it is used to sort the data.
In the second case, the records are returned inside a page, but I can live with that.

**EDIT**
https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-929 has been fixed, so with the new versions you'll be able to configure your resolver with a `null` fallbackPageable. That way, when pageable data (ie `page` and `size`) is present you retrieve one page, but when it's not you retrieve all records:

```
@Configuration
public class RestApiConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver customResolver(
        HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableResolver) {
        pageableResolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
        pageableResolver.setFallbackPageable(null);
        return pageableResolver;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could add your own methods to the Repository interface, and have a return type of `List<DomainObject>` or `Collection<DomainObject>` and no `Pageable` parameter. That will cause a non-paged response to be used. You could then point your legacy client at those methods instead of the default ones.

Or, you could configure the default page size to be very large. Set `spring.data.rest.default-page-size` in `application.properties`.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the cleanest solution, but the following code with allow you to pass `unpaged=true` as a query parameter, in order to get all the result in one page.

```
@Configuration
public class RestApiServletConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableResolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {
            @Override
            public Pageable resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory) {
                if ("true".equals(webRequest.getParameter(getParameterNameToUse("unpaged", methodParameter)))) {
                    return Pageable.unpaged();
                }

                return super.resolveArgument(methodParameter, mavContainer, webRequest, binderFactory);
            }
        };
        resolvers.add(pageableResolver);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The highest rated answer indicates a null for `setFallbackPageable`, which is no longer valid. Use the default static constructor for `PageRequest` like this:

```
@Configuration
public class RestApiConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver customResolver(
        HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableResolver) {
        pageableResolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
        pageableResolver.setFallbackPageable(PageRequest.of(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        pageableResolver.setMaxPageSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        return pageableResolver;
    }
}
```